# Unable to RegEx Replace

Tags: c#, .net, regex, exception

I have the following:

**Text:**

field id="25" ordinal="15" value="& $01234567890-$2000-"

**Regular Expression:**

(?<=value=").*(?=")

**Replacement String:**

& $09876543210-$2000-

---

When I run Regex Replace in Expresso - it crashes the application.

If I run Regex.Replace in C#, I receive the following Exception:

**ArgumentException**

*parsing "& $01234567890-$2000-" - Capture group numbers must be less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `$N` in the replacement pattern refers to the *Nth* capture group, so the regex engine thinks you want to refer to capture group number "09876543210" and throws the `ArgumentException`. If you want to use a literal `$` symbol in the replacement string then double it up to escape the symbol: `& $$09876543210-$$2000-`

```
string input = @"field id=""25"" ordinal=""15"" value=""& $01234567890-$2000-""";
string pattern = @"(?<=value="").*(?="")";
string replacement = "& $$09876543210-$$2000-";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

Also, your pattern is currently greedy and may match more than intended. To make it non-greedy use `.*?` so it doesn't end up matching beyond another double quote later in the string, or `[^"]*` so that it matches everything except a double quote. The updated pattern would be: `@"(?<=value="").*?(?="")"` or `@"(?<=value="")[^""]*(?="")"`. If you never expect the value attribute to be empty I suggest using `+` instead of `*` in any of the patterns to ensure it matches at least one character.